# How to make a program think a diffirent printer is the default printer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, printer

We have a card printer and a normal printer,
The software (which is unreplaceable sadly) which prints the cards, does not have an option to choose printer and will always use the default printer.

Is there a way to open a program with a switch to think another printer is default?

Comment: Wouldn't be much simpler to change the default to the one you need? After using it you can change it back to the other. Or is there another problem?

Comment: It is for an elderly employee who is having hard time entering the settings menu, also she uses both printers so many times during the day to a point where manually swapping default printer is laborious and pointless

Comment: Wrap the card-printing program startup in a script that sets the card printer as default, launches the program, and when the program exits, restores the default printer to what it was before running the program. Then, change the shortcut that launches the program to launch the script instead.

Comment: I tried that solution, but than we have seen that in practice it wouldn't work, the software is very big and takes about a minute to open, so the user does not close it at all until the day ends

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
PrinterPath = "\\research\library1"
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrinterPath
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter PrinterPath
```

This is from the Windows Scripting Host help file. Put into a file and name it *something.vbs*.

Comment: This seems to only change the default printer, I need to keep a default printer as one, and have another specific program think that another printer is the default at the same time.

Comment: You can change it then change it back. Else your program needs to support choosing printers.